# Mobile Capability for meta tags render en ASP.NET Mobile

Tags: asp.net, mobile, mobile-website, wurfl

Anybody knows what is mobile capability for render Meta Tags for each adapter?

I am using Marg.Wurfl to detect mobile device, and it maps wurfl capabilities to mobile capabilities, but it does not render meta tags.I have found **requiresXhtmlCssSuppression** capability in ASP.NET Mobile Controls XHTML Adapter Source, but it doesn´t work to me.

Thx in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After intensive using of [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/), i have found than Wml, Chtml and Html (Mobile) control adaptares uses: RequiredMetaTagNameValue, RequiresContentTypeMetaTag and PreferredRenderingMime capabilities for rendering meta tags, you can see them in RenderExtraHeadElements function in *FormAdapter (not in *PageAdapter, WTF).
But Xhtml controls adapter ([source code](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=9642963f-7c8d-4b26-a440-400e03ced4cb&displaylang=en)) doesn´t render metatag. I will create one.

Before, I thought the problem was a capabilities mapping, but now i think it is a XhtmlPageAdapter rendering problem.

more information?